# How can I get all "Auto-generated by YouTube" videos from a channel?

Tags: api, google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-dl

How can I get all "Auto-generated by YouTube" videos from a channel?

Here is an example song: *[La bohème - Kendji Girac](https://youtu.be/wauQivFuVhw)*

I didn't get it from its channel and even from search results. I got it from a playlist.

It is showing Auto-generated by YouTube.

How can I get all these videos from a specific channel?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the **`channel_id`** of the video you want to get the data from.

For getting the `channel_id` using the `video_id`, you can use the [videos:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint of the YouTube Data API - [example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22wauQivFuVhw%22%5D%7D).

Result:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "y1Zw7S-E_fPwC_hzp3fsJ7l0OCw",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "_1mzRopd5kh5bzsX66yES1K3i9g",
      "id": "wauQivFuVhw",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2018-07-26T02:10:16Z",
        "channelId": "UCNpFcllBHQk9wepKzMtouSQ",
        "title": "La bohème",
        "description": "Provided to YouTube by Universal Music Group\n\nLa bohème · Kendji Girac\n\nAznavour, sa jeunesse\n\n℗ 2014 Island Def Jam\n\nReleased on: 2014-01-01\n\nAssociated  Performer, Interprète  Vocal, Guitar: Kendji Girac\nAssociated  Performer, Programming, Keyboards: Christian Dessart\nAssociated  Performer, Keyboards, Programming: Rachid Mir\nStudio  Personnel, Recording  Engineer: Nabil Essemlani\nStudio  Personnel, Asst.  Recording  Engineer: Antonin Deniaud\nProducer, Studio  Personnel, Mixer: The Bionix\nStudio  Personnel, Mastering  Engineer: Eric Chevet\nAuthor: Jacques Plante\nComposer: Charles Aznavour\n\nAuto-generated by YouTube.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wauQivFuVhw/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wauQivFuVhw/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wauQivFuVhw/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wauQivFuVhw/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          },
          "maxres": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wauQivFuVhw/maxresdefault.jpg",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Kendji Girac - Topic",
        "tags": [
          "Kendji Girac ＫｅｎｄｊｉＧｉｒａｃ Aznavour",
          "sa jeunesse La bohème Ｌａ Ｂｏｈｅｍｅ La Boheme"
        ],
        "categoryId": "10",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "localized": {
          "title": "La bohème",
          "description": "Provided to YouTube by Universal Music Group\n\nLa bohème · Kendji Girac\n\nAznavour, sa jeunesse\n\n℗ 2014 Island Def Jam\n\nReleased on: 2014-01-01\n\nAssociated  Performer, Interprète  Vocal, Guitar: Kendji Girac\nAssociated  Performer, Programming, Keyboards: Christian Dessart\nAssociated  Performer, Keyboards, Programming: Rachid Mir\nStudio  Personnel, Recording  Engineer: Nabil Essemlani\nStudio  Personnel, Asst.  Recording  Engineer: Antonin Deniaud\nProducer, Studio  Personnel, Mixer: The Bionix\nStudio  Personnel, Mastering  Engineer: Eric Chevet\nAuthor: Jacques Plante\nComposer: Charles Aznavour\n\nAuto-generated by YouTube."
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  }
}
```

In this case, the **`channel_id`** of the video `wauQivFuVhw` is: **`UCNpFcllBHQk9wepKzMtouSQ`**.

Then, with this **`channel_id`**, change the second character to **`U`** as follows:

- Unmodified: *UCNpFcllBHQk9wepKzMtouSQ*
- Modified: *U**U**NpFcllBHQk9wepKzMtouSQ*

This modified id is the ***Uploads*** playlist of that said YouTube channel.

With this ***Uploads playlist_id***, you can use the [`Playlistitem:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint of the YouTube Data API to retrieve all the uploaded videos from the autogenerated channel.

This is [the example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UUNpFcllBHQk9wepKzMtouSQ%22%7D) with the uploads playlist_id described in this answer.

Comment: You meant: Modified: *U**U**NpFcllBHQk9wepKzMtouSQ*

Comment: By the way as clicking on the YouTube UI channel of the video, *stupidly* redirects to the wrong channel that is [UCgtt_xijZ03e0THlKDvPauw](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgtt_xijZ03e0THlKDvPauw), it would make sense to share to the OP how to get the channel id from the video id. To do so he can use [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) with `part=snippet` and the channel id associated to the video can be found in `item["snippet"]["channelId"]`

Comment: You're welcome @Marco Aurelio Fernandez Reyes. By the way FYI using `part=id,snippet` is equivalent to `part=snippet`.

Comment: Thank you, But now how to get all videos form JSON text , yes there are videos IDs with other information too. But I can't just copy every individual URL and add to a playlist.

Comment: Please wait a bit before posting the same comment.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison sorry!

Comment: @Marco Aurelio Fernandez Reyes How to add these information (videos ids etc) to a YouTube Playlist.

Comment: @ArmaanVerma https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73333482/how-can-i-get-all-auto-generated-by-youtube-videos-from-a-channel/73335905?noredirect=1#comment129527267_73333482 -see also **[ask]**

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Ok