# How can I add videos (channel content details with "video IDs" retrieved by YouTube API) to a YouTube playlist

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have Channel content details retrieved by [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UUNpFcllBHQk9wepKzMtouSQ%22%7D) in [JSON](https://www.writeurl.com/text/sl3udcqu7vfekn74yxfd/lhf3fm7f72zdecij0c09) format. How can I add those videos in a new YouTube playlist without copying every video ID and adding with URL individually. I'm able to filter [video IDs](https://www.writeurl.com/text/1ozt8sl3ga93z2je8yim/ndl85w9fogvb8m630ygs) with a text editor [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) .

Comment: Linked with [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73333482/7123660). I have already answered there.

Comment: You should see a request to edit_playlist, copy it as cURL (by right-clicking). Change at the end "actions":[{"addedVideoId":"YOUR_VIDEO_ID","action":"ACTION_ADD_VIDEO"}] to "actions":[{"addedVideoId":"YOUR_VIDEO_ID_0","action":"ACTION_ADD_VIDEO"}, {"addedVideoId":"YOUR_VIDEO_ID_1","action":"ACTION_ADD_VIDEO"}   IDs are different this time no same, and If I have to do this then I can simply put video IDs with YouTube URL ,then save it to a playlist, which I have done today, [myPlaylist](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoocKhB4VOHsQ49FaCGnKvPvtDksvKfuK) fortunately there were just 90 items.

Comment: "IDs are different this time no same" doesn't make sense to me. `YOUR_VIDEO_ID_N` can be any arbitrary YouTube video, so I don't see why you are talking about different or same.

Comment: I'm suprised ur not understanding, I can't put individually every ID in these, that takes so much time, there are 257 video IDs time or can be more. I am looking for another API which understands the JSON format provide by YouTube API and then create a Playlist and then add videos to it, I won't go to copy another 257 urls this time.

Comment: And I am using Google too.

Comment: "I can't put individually every ID in these, that takes so much time" I already told you to use a programming language with a library supporting JSON deserialization as `python` and `json` in order not to do this by hand...